# Getting difference column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-field

I want to create difference column using two tables Table 1 and Table 2 , I want to create Table 3 which is having difference of count column using DAX formula

[image]

Comment: Please paste your tables as copiable text next time

Comment: Sure Davide bacci

Comment: Was your problem solved

Answer (score 2):

```
Table3 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(Table1[Product]), VALUES(Table2[Product])) ),
    "@Diff", 
    VAR a = LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[Count], Table1[Product], Table1[Product])
    VAR b = LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[Count], Table2[Product], Table1[Product])
    RETURN a-b
    
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
Table3 = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Table1[YourKeyColumn],
    "Count_Table1", COUNTROWS(Table1),
    "Count_Table2", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2))
    "Difference", [Count_Table1] - [Count_Table2]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**